# Concurrent Merge Issues

Tags: sql-server-2012, concurrency, merge

A (simplified) model of my application has several processes dumping data into the table below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InputData]
(
    [InputId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Dts] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Quality] [int] NULL,
    [Value] [float] NULL,
    [Observed] [float] NULL,
    [Changed]  AS (case when [Value] IS NULL AND [Observed] IS NULL then (0) when [Value] IS NOT NULL AND [Observed] IS NOT NULL then case when abs([Value]-[Observed])<(1.000000000000000e-010) then (0) else (1) end else (1) end),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.InputData] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [InputId] ASC,
        [Dts] ASC
    )
    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) 
ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_dbo.InputData] ON [dbo].[InputData]
(
    [InputId] ASC,
    [Dts] ASC
)
INCLUDE ([Value]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

All data is merged into the table using the following process:

1. The data is bulk copied (SqlBulkCopy in C#) into a staging (i.e. Temporary) table and associated with a GUID.
2. A stored procedure is called to merge the data into the table given the correct GUID.
3. The staging table is deleted.

The stored procedure used to dump the data is given below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_InputData_MergeData]
    -- The identifier associated with the merge operation.
    @Id AS CHAR(32),

    -- A value indicating whether to overwrite any existing data.
    @OverwriteExistingData AS BIT = 0
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
            EXEC sp_getapplock @Resource = N'InputData', @LockMode = N'Exclusive', @LockOwner = N'Transaction', @LockTimeout = 15000;

            DECLARE @Query AS NVARCHAR(MAX) =
                N'MERGE INTO ' +
                    N'[SCP].[dbo].[InputData] WITH ( HOLDLOCK ) AS dst ' +
                N'USING ' +
                N'( ' +
                    N'SELECT ' +
                        N'[InputId], ' +
                        N'[Dts], ' +
                        N'[Quality], ' +
                        N'[Value] ' +
                    N'FROM ' +
                        N'#InputData_' + @Id + N' ' +
                N') src ' +
                N'ON ' +
                    N'(dst.[InputId] = src.[InputId]) AND ' +
                    N'(dst.[Dts] = src.[Dts]) ' +
                N'WHEN MATCHED AND (@OverwriteExistingData = 1) THEN ' +
                    N'UPDATE ' +
                    N'SET ' +
                        N'dst.[Quality] = src.[Quality], ' +
                        N'dst.[Value] = src.[Value] ' +
                N'WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN ' +
                    N'INSERT ' +
                    N'( ' +
                        N'[InputId], ' +
                        N'[Dts], ' +
                        N'[Quality], ' +
                        N'[Value], ' +
                        N'[Observed] ' +
                    N') ' +
                    N'VALUES ' +
                    N'( ' +
                        N'src.[InputId], ' +
                        N'src.[Dts], ' +
                        N'src.[Quality], ' +
                        N'src.[Value], ' +
                        N'src.[Value] ' +
                    N');';

            DECLARE @Parameters AS NVARCHAR(MAX) =
                N'@OverwriteExistingData AS BIT';

            EXEC sp_executesql @Query, @Parameters, @OverwriteExistingData = @OverwriteExistingData;
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

        DECLARE @ErrorNumber AS INT = ERROR_NUMBER();
        PRINT 'Error Number: ' + CAST(@ErrorNumber AS VARCHAR(10));

        DECLARE @ErrorLine AS INT = ERROR_LINE();
        PRINT 'Line Number: ' + CAST(@ErrorLine AS VARCHAR(10));

        THROW;
    END CATCH
END;

GO
```

My problem is that as the level of concurrency increases, I am having issues with deadlocks. There are a configured number of realtime processes that dump data into the table on a given interval, as well as any number of batch processes that can be spun up by the user to backfill data at any time. Basically, I am trying to dump data into this table from a high number of processes without getting deadlocked.

**Problem**:

I ran a trace on the locking behavior in SQL Server, and this is a representative image:

[image: Trace Profiler]

I'm assuming the lock escalation events come from the sp_getapplock call, but I may be incorrect. The deadlock that I am seeing currently is highlighted.

**Questions**:

1. Is it possible to do this without sp_getapplock?
2. Am I approaching this correctly? I don't have much experience with database work, so any general tips about how to approach this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you queue the input processes? I understand the need for locking, as multiple processes doing merge simultaneously may give unwanted results. Queuing the input processes and running them one at a time would solve the deadlock issue as long as the app/users doing the input understand that it's a queue.

Comment: If you can insure you're only merging one GUID set at a time and you can indicate when a GUID set is fully loaded before starting to process it there is no reason the Merge couldn't be ran synchronously for each GUID (or sets of GUIDs) with Dirty Reads which may cut down on deadlocks. Generally bulk inserting into a table should have minimal deadlocking itself but the Merge creates lot of opportunities if it's not being limited to known 'safe' rows .

Comment: I have to say you have a design "bug" with your unique index [IX_dbo.InputData] because it has the same columns ([InputId] and [Dts]) as your primary key (which automatically has a clustered unique index). The least I can say is that this is duplicate, please just remove this [IX_dbo.InputData] index, and it will at least help your insertion workload.

Comment: BTW, I'd add sp_releaseapplock after COMMIT TRANSACTION.

Comment: No need for the sp_releaseapplock, as it's transaction scoped.